# Should these META badge designations be re-evaluated?

Tags: discussion, badges

Here we have 2 Moderation Badges for your consideration; Tag Editor and Research Assistant.  Below is the description of each tag level, and a description of these two badges:
[image]

A Bronze badge is supposed to be "easy to get", yet with only 177 Tag Editor badges awarded I'd say it's really not that easy.

A Silver badge is "less common", yet only **4** Research Assistant badges have been awarded.  I'd consider 50 Wiki edits to be an "important contribution", wouldn't you?

The only badge awarded less times than Research Assistant is the Legendary badge, which has only been awarded 3 times.

Is it time to bump these up a notch and make Tag Editor a Silver and Research Assistant a Gold?

Comment: What site is this on?

Comment: I don't think it should be silver / gold, as it's not particularly difficult to get on [so], and that inconsistency between the sites probably isn't good. If this already happens with some other badges, perhaps the requirements should be lowered on Meta.

Comment: Go ahead, and suggest a good tag wiki edit. There, when it is accepted you get a bronze badge. Was that so hard to get?

Comment: Maybe Tag Editor is still Bronze-worthy.  But with all the wiki's being refined over the years, it's certainly more difficult to suggest 50 edits.  With only 4 being awarded, don't you think that's worth more than a Silver?  And it **is** an important contribution to edit wikis.

Comment: Like @Dukeling said, you're looking at the meta site. On the main site, 10445 people have the bronze badge and 118 people have the silver badge. Who cares about such badges on meta?

Comment: @JohnnyBones: Meta is different from other sites; there are not that many tags **here**. But Meta is not the *only* site. So far, 9 people received the bronze badge on Stack Overflow. The silver badge has been awarded 118 times, but only because most people don't bother with tag wiki edits, *not* because it is that hard.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think their rarity speaks to difficulty - I think you just have less people editing tag wikis. Remember, for Tag Editor the requirement is

> First tag wiki edit

And that's not really difficult.

So no, I don't think we need to adjust their rankings.

Comment: These wiki's have been refined over the years.  The ability to make an edit now has declined dramatically.  If it was still that easy, I'd think there would be more than 177 awarded.

Comment: @JohnnyBones there are many new tags every day...

Comment: @JohnnyBones Yes, established tags should end up with better Wikis over time. But remember that tags do get added, and those need edit lovin' too.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: Have you looked at these badges over on *Stack Overflow*? I earned the Research Assistant badge just yesterday myself. I didn't especially go out of my way to earn it either. 9 people got the Bronze badge *just today*.

Comment: I'd say *"speaks to the difficulty of people editing tag wikis"*. I like to edit a lot and rarely touch tags :/